# Need help on a formula I use in basic MRP excel for in automotive

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using this formula however I need to only search of a partial of my `$J$1`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(PartPointOfInstall!$A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(PartPointOfInstall!$B$2:$U$1600)/(PartPointOfInstall!$B$2:$U$1600=$J$1),ROW(PartPointOfInstall!1:1))),"")
```

I had tried to add `$J$1&"*"` and no luck.  Any help would be nice.  I use this code a lot now I just want to give a return on part of the searched text. Which is `$J$1`

$J$1 in this case FB.  I have a lot of parts that start with FB.  Looking to list them all. I have $J$1 as a list with other things to look for so can not change $J$1.

Comment: What part of the text in `J1` are you looking for? An example may be useful here

Comment: maybe `find()`...